# Rails 3.0, ActionMailer delivery not working, no error message displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, actionmailer

I'd like to play around with sending mail from Rails in a development environment. My message is getting rendered (I can see it in the terminal I'm running `rails console` in).

In `config/development.rb` I have (yes, the port is really 26):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address  => "mail.mydomain.com",
  :port  => 26,
  :user_name  => "me@mydomain.com",
  :password  => "removed",
  :authentication  => :login
}
```

I have in `mailers/user_mailer`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@mydomain.com"
  def send_an_email
    mail(:to => "me@gmail.com", :subject => "Test from Rails")
  end
end
```

I have a view that's getting rendered properly in `views/user_mailer/send_an_email.text.erb`. I'm calling `UserMailer.send_an_email.deliver` upon a page request.

Rails doesn't complain about my configuration. I see the message in the `rails server` console output. However, I never get an e-mail, and I don't see any error messages in the console output (as you can see above, `raise_delivery_errors = true`!.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Were you ever able to figure out the cause of yours?

Comment: A non-working smtp connection will also behave in a similar manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steve, by chance have you made sure you're calling the deliver method?

```
mail(:to => "me@gmail.com", :subject => "Test from Rails").deliver
```

I forgot to do that, and was quite confused by the lack of errors. :)

Comment: I'm no longer working on that project. But I will accept this unless someone objects.

Comment: Is there a way to test the deliver method? so if it fails you can redirect the user or warn them?

Comment: In Rails 4 #.deliver is deprecated and from version 5 #deliver.now will have to be used